# Vue cannot change attribute in nested v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, v-for

I get an array of objects and I add to it the attribute `clicked=false`, so I can later add or remove a class using vue bind and the value of that attribute

Then I turn this array of objects to an object structure, so I can render the items by type, in the rendering of the loop.

I use a click method on each list item to change the `clicked` attribute, but it never changes.

How can I do this?

The object has this structure

```
grouped:{
  typeA: [
   {
    clicked: false,
    text: "a1",
    type: "typeA"
   }, 
   {
    clicked: false,
    text: "a2",
    type: "typeA"
   }
  ],
  typeB: [
   {
    clicked: false,
    text: "b1",
    type: "typeB"
   }
  ]
}
```

And then to render by type I do

```
  <div v-for="(group, type) in grouped" :key="type">
    <b>{{type}}</b>
    <div  v-for="(item, index) in group" :key="index" @click="eventItemClick(item)" >
      {{item.text}}   {{item.clicked}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

all the `eventItemClick` method does is

```
      eventItemClick(item){    
        item.clicked = !item.clicked;
      },
```

I created a simple [js fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/slevin/fren70ov/20/) that demonstrates. Just remember to click the `group` button to group the array and render the list

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're running into the [reactivity caveat](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) because you are trying to use data properties that don't exist at the time of rendering.

Use `Vue.set` when setting those properties:

```js
this.todos.forEach(e => { 
   this.$set(e, 'clicked', false);  // `Vue.set` in a module
});
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. I get `ReferenceError: Vue is not defined` What am I missing here? Thanks

Comment: Hi, `Vue` should be defined in your fiddle, since you use `new Vue`.  But I edited to show you the component syntax of `set`

Comment: Thanks for the fix. I get no errors now, but still does not work. Maybe I should use some sort of get in the `eventItemClick` ? Thanks

Comment: Here is your fiddle with my answer integrated:  https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/6nq73w51/   (Notice it works both with this edit and the original)  So I'm not sure what you're referring to